# Where to send SamlLogoutResponse

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, opensaml

During SP-initiated SSO, the Authentication Request(AuthnRequest) can specify to which Assertion Consumer Service (ACS) the Security Assertion Markup Language(SAML) Response has to be sent in the AssertionConsumerURL.
Similarly in IDP initiated SSLO where should we send the SamlLogoutResponse to ?
In the [logout request](https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/examples/logout-request) example I dont see AssertionConsumerURL. Do we have to send the response to what is specified in the destination parameter?

Answer (score 0):

ACS and SLO (Single Logout) are different endpoints in SAML.

They are normally specified in the metadata.